# Adding data to user account trough custom UI in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to add data to a users account trough custom UI? I do not want to use a edit profile policy. I just need the user to fill in one thing that then has to get stored in his/her account. Is that possible?

This has to be inside of a xamarin.forms app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native client can invoke the Azure AD Graph API to update the user object.

However, for the native client to access to the Azure AD Graph API, you should bridge them using a proxy API (I will call this the User API), so that the native client doesn't need a client secret, as follows.

At design-time:

1. Register the native client using the Azure AD B2C portal.
2. [Register the User API using the Azure AD portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#register-your-application-in-your-tenant) and [grant the **Read and write directory data** permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-create-read-and-update-permissions-for-your-application).

At runtime:

1. The native client redirects the end user to the Azure AD B2C v2.0 endpoint for sign-in. Azure AD B2C issues an ID token containing the user identifier.
2. The native client invokes the User API with this ID token. The User API validates the ID token.
3. The User API acquires an access token from the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint using the application credentials that were created at design-time in step 2.
4. The User API invokes the Azure AD Graph API, passing the user identifier that was received in step 2, with the access token that was issued in step 3, and then updates the user object.

Comment: Forgot I had this question. This is indeed what I came up with as well! Thanks for the reply anyway. One thing that seems weird to me however is that the documentation says only a older version of the API can be used for this purpose. Is that truly the case?